# Checking if string is in table

Tags: postgresql

Hi I have table called mytable and 1 column first_name , how can I check if 'John' is in this table and return the result as true/false.

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize a [EXISTS-query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-subquery.html):

```
select exists (select * from mytable where mytable.first_name = 'John')
```

The above query will return a boolean which will be true if the sub-query inside the braces returns any rows at all; the boolean will false if the sub-query return no rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END
FROM mytable
WHERE first_name LIKE '%John%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM mytable WHERE first_name LIKE 'John';
```

returns number of occurrences. If there is no John in table, returns zero.